# Search between two dates

Tags: sql, date

I am currently using this code for searching between two dates on my database:

```
SELECT *
FROM reports
WHERE user_name = '$valueToSearch' AND
      work_date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Last year, it was smoothly working when searching, but while my database is populated by different date inputs, and I tried to search between dates, it outputs the selected dates plus the last year's input with the selected date.

Example: when I select 05/12/2021 - 05/26/2021, it shows from 05/12/2020 to 05/26/2020 and 05/12/2021 to 05/26/2021.

Why is that?

Comment: Can you show the exact queries being run rather than just the query with the variable inserts? What DBMS and version are you using?

Comment: Please show the relevant subset of the schema for the table — the column type for `work_date` is particularly important.  How are `$startDate` and `$endDate` formatted?  Are they string variables with the values you suggest?  Does the search result include dates from 2021-05-26 or does it stop with 2021-05-25?

Comment: $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch']; - "a list box consist of employee names"
$startDate = $_POST['dteFrom']; - "date picker 1"
$endDate = $_POST['dteTo']; - "date picker 2"


$query = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE user_name = '$valueToSearch' AND work_date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate' ORDER BY id DESC";

$res_data = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

Comment: Sounds like you made the mistake of storing dates as strings

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Yes, they are all String variables. The search result that exact month and day of what I input, but it shows the 2 different years, not the exact year I input.

Comment: Please edit the extra information into the question where you can format it.  Then delete your comments and flag this one “no longer needed”.

Comment: Use parameters!  Don't munge query strings with constant values.  And fix the data types!  Don't store dates as strings.